# CircleCI Swift with Postgres connection issues

Tags: swift, postgresql, docker, circleci, circleci-2.0

I am working with my [repo](https://github.com/marcusjwhelan/swiftDevOpsTester) to build a test app for swift with circleCI and postgres but when it comes to testing I can't seem to grasp how to connect the two images in the testing phase.

I am running

```sh
circleci local execute --job build
```

Which should build both the swift and postgres images. I give them both the same env variables I give in the application. However I get this error when trying to run it. In my experience when trying to set up the two docker containers with compose this error was showing up when my api could not connect to the db container over the network.

```
Test Case 'AppTests.RemoveUserTest' started at 2019-04-09 19:46:15.380
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: NIO.ChannelError.connectFailed(NIO.NIOConnectionError(host: "db", port: 5432, dnsAError: Optional(NIO.SocketAddressError.unknown(host: "db", port: 5432)), dnsAAAAError: Optional(NIO.SocketAddressError.unknown(host: "db", port: 5432)), connectionErrors: [])): file /home/buildnode/jenkins/workspace/oss-swift-4.2-package-linux-ubuntu-16_04/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 184
```

I know it says it failed because of a try statement but that try statement is failing because it's requesting actions from Postgres which is not there. Any ideas?

My current config.yml for circleci

```
version: 2

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: swift:4.2
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: test
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
          POSTGRES_DB: test
          DB_HOSTNAME: db
          PORT: 5432
      - image: postgres:11.2-alpine
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: test
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
          POSTGRES_DB: test
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: apt-get update -qq
      - run: apt-get install -yq libssl-dev pkg-config wget
      - run: apt-get install -y postgresql-client || true
      - run:
          name: install dockerize
          command: wget https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize/releases/download/$DOCKERIZE_VERSION/dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz && tar -C /usr/local/bin -xzvf dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz && rm dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz
          environment:
            DOCKERIZE_VERSION: v0.3.0
      - run:
          name: Wait for db
          command: dockerize -wait tcp://localhost:5432 -timeout 1m
      - run: 
          name: Compile code
          command: swift build
      - run: 
          name: Run unit tests
          command: swift test

  release:
    docker:
      - image: swift:4.2
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: 
          name: Compile code with optimizations
          command: swift build -c release
  push-to-docker-hub:
    docker:
      - image: docker:latest
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: |
            apk add --update --no-cache curl jq python py-pip
      - run:
          name: Build Docker Image
          command: |
            docker build -t api .
            docker tag api <>/repo:latest
            docker tag api <>/repo:$CIRCLE_SHA1
            docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASS
            docker push <>/repo:latest
            docker push <>/repo:$CIRCLE_SHA1
#      - persist_to_workspace:
#          root: ./
#          paths:
#            - k8s-*.yml

workflows:
  version: 2
  tests:
    jobs:
      - build
      - push-to-docker-hub:
          requires:
            - build
          context: dockerhub
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
      #- linux-release
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the hostname for the database to `db`, but not defining that anywhere. You need to name your Docker container to match the `DB_HOSTNAME` environment variable like so https://github.com/vapor/postgresql/blob/master/circle.yml#L8

Comment: Awesome, for anyone wondering it worked. All I had to do was change the `name` field to `db` which is also stated in my code as well.